# Why does it say 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined' when it is defined?

Tags: javascript, dom

I defined a variable, and I want to append a child to it, but for some reason, I get an error that says the value is undefined, so I can't use appendChild().

Since I found some sources say that it's because the assets have not loaded yet, I tried using window.onload, but I really want my function to run when the button is clicked.

```
  document.getElementById("calc").onclick = function calculate(){
        var rate = +document.getElementById("rate").value/100;
        var years = +document.getElementById("years").value;
        var principal = +document.getElementById("principal").value;

        var i = 0;

        while(i < years){
          var afterRate = principal * rate;
          var totalAmount = principal += afterRate;
          var interestValue = document.createElement("div");
          var division = document.getElementById('divis');

          interestValue.style.color = "white";
          interestValue.style.fontFamily = "futura";
          interestValue.innerHTML = totalAmount;
          document.division.appendChild(interestValue);

          var lastButton = document.getElementById("last");
          var clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");
          var roundButton = document.getElementById("round");

          i++
        }
    }
```

I thought that the interestValue in my function would be added to the div I defined, but instead, I got the message, 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined.'

Comment: `document.division` is not defined anywhere in your code - perhaps you meant `division.appendChild(interestValue);` not `document.division.appendChild(interestValue);`

Comment: Thank you! That was a pretty silly mistake, but that was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Posting answer for this, same as what `@Jaromanda X` explained in comment.

```
  document.getElementById("calc").onclick = function calculate(){
    var rate = +document.getElementById("rate").value/100;
    var years = +document.getElementById("years").value;
    var principal = +document.getElementById("principal").value;

    var i = 0;

    while(i < years){
      var afterRate = principal * rate;
      var totalAmount = principal += afterRate;
      var interestValue = document.createElement("div");
      var division = document.getElementById('divis');

      interestValue.style.color = "white";
      interestValue.style.fontFamily = "futura";
      interestValue.innerHTML = totalAmount;
      division.appendChild(interestValue); // Removed document

      var lastButton = document.getElementById("last");
      var clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");
      var roundButton = document.getElementById("round");

      i++
    }
}
```

> `document.division` is not defined anywhere in your code - perhaps you
>   meant `division.appendChild(interestValue);` not
>   `document.division.appendChild(interestValue);`